# Is it more readable to use defines everywhere, or hide them inside properties?

Tags: c#, c-preprocessor, readability

That's an example code that I'm talking about:

```
    bool DefinedProperty
    {
        get
        {
#if DEFINE_SOMETHING
            return true;
#else
            return false;
#endif          
        }
    }
...
    if (!DefinedProperty)
        someObject.someMethod();
...
    bool someBool = DefinedProperty && SomeOtherMethod() == SomeClass.SomeProperty;
```

I think that it's not very readable, because in order to understand it, I have to go back to DefinedProperty. It seems to me that more straightforward version would be better:

```
#if DEFINE_SOMETHING
    someObject.someMethod();
#endif  
...
#if DEFINE_SOMETHING
    bool someBool = DefinedProperty && SomeOtherMethod() == SomeClass.SomeProperty;
#else
    bool someBool = false;
#endif
```

However, a colleague of mine argues that the first version looks more simple and the less defines are used, the better.

Which option is more readable?

Comment: if I have to vote I prefer the first method. Because then I directly relate my Object variable to DEFINE member, then whatever I do is based on my object variable then using Define everywhere in code. And it means virtually I was using single variable in code.

Comment: @SumitGupta, although I'm not yet sure about what option is best, I think your comment is in fact a good answer.

Comment: Thanks, my comment is simply based on logical flow rather than individual choice of writing a code. I learn to use fewer variable they keep coding easy, so choose that is more logical than what you prefer.

Comment: `because in order to understand it, I have to go back to DefinedProperty` ideally the name would tell you what it represents so that you don't need to know internals.